# Titanium Android Tabs

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to achieve the two tabs as below using titanium for android. 
These are not the normal tabs, so how do I achieve them ?

[image]

Thanks !!

Comment: So you want them to look like these tabs from iPhone? You don't want to use native Android UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These seem to be buttons on a toolbar and not tabs. 
As there is no support for Android toolbars in Titanium (I'm not sure if Android a thing called toolbar) you will have to fake it. 
To get the same results on Android you would have to use regular createView and add background and different buttons in it. you will also have to make the buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

Use two Buttons and a ViewFlipper that contains different ListViews.

Answer (score 0):

[custom tabgroup class working on android and iphone](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/46801/giving-to-the-community-custom-tabgroup-class-working-on-android-and-iphone) may be useful to you. See the screen shots [for android](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143939/tabs_xcompat_android.png) and [for iphone](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143939/tabs_xcompat_iphone.png) also.